# Database design: how to design this peculiar relationship

Tags: mysql, database-design, polymorphic-associations

I'm pretty new to designing databases, and i'm encountering a challenge;

In a lab, DNA samples are prepared from tissue samples. These tissue samples have attributes such as species and location. It is possible, but not always the case, that different tissue samples are mixed before DNA sample preparation.

So, there are 3 tables, with following attributes:

A table, `Tissue_sample`:

```
- ID 
- location 
- species
```

A table, `Mixed_tissue_sample`:

```
- ID 
- tissue samples which are mixed together
```

A table, `DNA_sample`:

```
- ID 
- tissue_sample OR mixed_tissue_sample
```

It should be possible to retrieve all tissue samples from which a DNA sample is prepared.

What is the most elegant way to fit this into a database? And is possible to do this in the MySQL workbench?

Comment: Is there such a concept as a "mixed tissue sample" which is not mixed for purposes of a DNA sample?  I ask because it sounds like really you just need 2 tables - DNA sample, with a one-to-many relationship to tissue sample. Therefore, one row per DNA sample, joining to one or more rows in tissue sample.  But if the mixed tissue sample has meaning or purpose separate from the DNA sample, you would need something more complex.

Comment: Yes, the mixed_tissue_sample has a purpose, and should be an entity on its own. It will have additional attributes, which are different from tissue_sample. And multiple DNA_samples can be created of a mixed_tissue_sample.

Comment: Would a DNA sample ever be created from a _combination_ of multiple mixed tissue samples? (say, from 6 total species previously mixed in 2 different groups of 3)

Comment: No, that is not going to happen. Mixed tissue samples will always be created from 'singular' tissue samples.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski That's how aliens and zombies are made

Comment: @Strawberry Or the new deadly hybrid dinosaur in yesterday's Jurassic World trailer...

Answer (score 0):

Define two fields in DNA table to reference a single or a mixed tissue sample. One of these fields will remain NULL.

> tissue: id, location, species
>
> mixed: id, ...
>
> mixed_tissues: mixed_id, tissue_id
>
> DNA: id, tissue_id, mixed_id

And yes, you can create these tables in MySQL workbench.

Comment: See polymorphic association anti-pattern

Answer (score 0):

First, resolve the relation between `Tissue_sample` and `Mixed_tissue_sample`. 1 or more Tissue_sample defines a Mixed_tissue_sample, therefore the relation is 1:n and you need to have another column at `Tissue_sample`, which will serve as a `foreign key` to `Mixed_tissue_sample`. You can get the tissue samples of a mixed tissue sample by joining the two tables upon the identified of `Mixed_tissue_sample`.

Second, you need to resolve the `DNA_sample`. You need a `foreign key` to `Tissue_sample` and to `Mixed_tissue_sample` as well.

You can make sure a `DNA_sample` has no connection to both by creating a trigger which will prevent any `inserts` or `updates` which would result in a record of `DNA_sample` which has values for both `foreign keys` if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

Use table inheritance.

Either put tissue sample and mixed tissue sample all in the same table (single table inheritance), with a "type" column,

or put them in two different tables with their primary key pointing to a common table (class table inheritance). DNA sample table would point at this common table.

Comment: This looks like the most elegant solution. Thanks for all the answers. I think I will visit this forum more often!